# Passing data from mongo to ejs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ejs

(This is my first question here, I'm excited :))

2 files: index.js (what I'm using to connect to the mongo, find and toArray the data), and admin.ejs where I want to display the data (user records: username, first name, last name...).

index.js:

```
var db = MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err)
        throw err;

    db.collection("Users").find().toArray(function (err, result) {
        var i, count;
        for (i = 0, count = result.length; i < count; i++) {
            myArr.push(result[i]);
        }
        myArr = JSON.stringify(myArr);
    });

    console.log(myArr); // just for testing
    console.log("connected to the mongoDB !");
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('Admin', {
        myVar: myArr
    });
});
```

admin.ejs:

```
var myOtherVar = JSON.parse('<%-myVar%>');
```

In the broswer "view source code" I can see

```
var myOtherVar = JSON.parse('[{"_id":"567a6fd307200cb90f7af961","Username":"Yogev" ...
```

so I know that the data passes correctly, but any atempt to use it fails - the JS "see" it as  `object Object` and not as an array...

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll just need to use object notation to access the data.

```
console.log(myOtherVar[0].Username)
// Returns 'Yogev'
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you send a object to the view

```
res.view('Admin',{ myVar : myArr});
```

This way you use it in the view

```
<h1> <%= myVar[0].property %></h1>
```

In this case you use `<%=` because  `<%` does not print the returned value by the expression just after it.